# operacion con decimales

Tags: vb.net

Tengo la siguiente operación realizada:

```
DataGridView22.Item (IndexColumnImporte, L) .Value = Result
```

Resultado es equivalente a este número `158974`

A este `result` lo devuelvo a un `datagridview`.

Necesito que todos los resultados salgan de esta manera `1589.74`

Answer (score 1):

ya lo resolví de la siguiente forma:

```
DataGridView22.Item(IndiceColumnaImporte, L).Value = String.Format("{0:##0.00}", resul / 100).Replace(",", ".")
```

gracias de todas formas.